# charAt producing different outputs

Tags: java, charat

Now this code works absolutely fine in one machine but in another just simply refuses to output the correct result.

It is a simple Initials output request. I have no queries with the code but my question is why is it outputting numbers instead of letters?

When running the code from my laptop using Eclipse(Kepler) no issues and I get letters. If i use one of the desktops available to me and the same version of Eclipse I get an integer as a result. It may be settings but I just cant figure out why. And rewriting the code makes no change to the output

```
import java.util.Scanner;

 public class InitialHere {

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //Using input keyboard

    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

    String firstname,lastname;

    //Requesting names
    System.out.print("What is your first name?");
    firstname = kb.nextLine();

    System.out.print("What is your last name?");
    lastname = kb.nextLine();

    //Calculating the initials
    char achar = firstname.charAt(0);
    char bchar = lastname.charAt(0);

    //Output
    System.out.println("Your initials are " + achar + bchar);
```

Comment: What are the inputs and outputs exactly?

Comment: Imagine the inputs are Tom Walton the result should be TW. But it ends up being 171.

Comment: Oh really, Did you sysout the `firstname` and `lastname` prior to it?

Comment: What you done the code,Everything works fine?What thing you expect in the code?

Comment: The idea was not to sysout the names and just sysout the initials as the result of the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
System.out.println("Your initials are " + achar + "" + bchar);
```

I think this shouldn't happen but it smells like char addition. For example:

```
char a='a';
char b='b';
System.out.println( a+b ); ==> 195
```

Comment: This worked perfectly Thank you very much. Any reason why it works on some machines and not on others? left me a bit confused

Comment: Not really. I think this shouldn't happen at all and would be a compiler bug if it does.

Comment: @Snorrarcisco the only reason I can think of is your JVM version which might be different on different machines.

Comment: @SavTheCoder cheers for that didn't think of it. Will check machines for different JVM versions.

Comment: @SavTheCoder: Even with different JVMs this shouldn't happen. If anything this could be a compiler problem. The Associativity of operators is well defined. see e.g.: Example 15.18.1-1. String Concatenation http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html